# Vim - Macro to expand verilog bus

Tags: regex, vim, verilog

I can't seem to be able to create a vim macro that does the following:

Source:

```
this_is_a_bus[10:0]
another_bus[2:0]
```

Required Dest:

```
this_is_a_bus[10]
this_is_a_bus[9]
this_is_a_bus[8]
this_is_a_bus[7]
this_is_a_bus[6]
this_is_a_bus[5]
this_is_a_bus[4]
this_is_a_bus[3]
this_is_a_bus[2]
this_is_a_bus[1]
this_is_a_bus[0]
another_bus[2]
another_bus[1]
another_bus[0]
```

What I tried to do:
I can search for `\d\+:\d\+` and put the cursor on the first number, then copy that with `yw` to the memory. However I can't seem to be able to tell vim to run the paste command on the basis of the number in the register.

Am I approaching this the wrong way? What's the suggested way to create something like this?

Comment: If you want it to be dynamic, you need write function to do it. Like auto generating for `[10:3], [20:1], [8:5]...` well vim can do it for sure, but is it a must? awk or other script language can make it easier.

Comment: Why do you want to expand the bus? verilog has tons of ways to assign multiple values to a single bus. When I worked with verilog, there was never a need to split the bus like this.

Comment: @Kent: Unfortunately, it is a must in vim as other infrastructure is based on that. A function would also be great but I am unfamiliar with vimrc function syntax. Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: @FDinoff: Your answer puzzles me. I've been working with Verilog for the better part of the past decade, and this is quite a trivial need. It is required for trace assignments, for example, or for other scripts usage. It is also handy when you'd like to send several bits of a certain bus down different routes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function, which could do the expansion automatically by single keystroke. (`<F6>` in this case)

```
fun! ExpandIt()
    let pat = '^\([^][]\+\)\[\(\d\+\):\(\d\+\)\]\s*'
    let line = getline('.')
    let lnr = line('.')
    if line !~ pat
        return
    endif
    let exestr = substitute(line,pat,'range(\2,\3,-1)','g')
    let text = substitute(line,pat,'\1','g')
    exec 'let range='.exestr
    let result = []
    for i in range
        call add(result, text.'['.i.']')
    endfor
    call append(lnr, result)
    exec lnr'.d'    
endf
nnoremap <F6> :call ExpandIt()<cr>
```

- source this file, or put it in your vimrc.
- the last line creates a mapping, it allows you to press `<F6>` on that line to do expansion
- if the line is not in `xxxx[number:number]` format, nothing would happen
- I didn't check error case, like `xxx[1:10]` or `xxx[000:000]`

I did a little test, and it looks like:

[image]

Comment: BTW, is there any way to make it work with busses that have a prefix with brackets and whitespaces, like this:

xxxx [a to b] my_bus[10:0]

?

Comment: @ygoncho I didn't get you. what the output would be if the line is like that?

Comment: xxxx [a to b] my_bus[10] \n
xxxx [a to b] my_bus[9] \n ... etc. It's just that the first regex doesn't catch these kinds of busses for me

Comment: @ygoncho Oh, I might have understood, try replacing the corresponding line in func with this `let pat = '^\(.*\)\[\(\d\+\):\(\d\+\)\]\s*$'` I didn't test, but give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a macro to accomplish this task. Start with the following line:

```
this_is_a_bus[10]
```

Then record the macro:

```
qqyyp<c-x>q
```

Then playback the macro via `@q`. Even better we can give it a count, `9@q`.

#### Explanation of macro

- `q{reg}` starts recording the macro and saves the macro into register, `{reg}`. e.g. `qq`
- `yy` copies the whole line
- `p` paste the newly copied line below the current line (the cursor is on the new line)
- `<c-x>` will decrement the first number it finds from the current cursor position
- `q` pressing `q` while recording a macro will end recording
- `@{reg}` will playback a macro inside `{reg}`. e.g. `@q` to playback register `q`
- `[count]@{reg}`: `@` can take a count do playback the macro `[count]` times. e.g. `9@q`
- `@@` will replay the last used `@{reg}` command. Optionally `@@` can take a count as well

For more help see:

```
:h q
:h @
:h @@
:h ctrl-x
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment and explanation, however while this is the path I reluctantly followed - as my question stated, I'm looking for something more automated with single click, that will run the macro for the amount of times that is denoted by the register, and not manually (such as the 9@q in your solution). 
Your solution is problematic if I have a list of many many busses and I want to expand it in a single stroke.