# Macro Vim - expand multiple Verilog Bus

Tags: regex, vim, verilog

I'm trying to implement Macro to expand Verilog Bus as [Vim - Macro to expand verilog bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823265/vim-macro-to-expand-verilog-bus) and this is really working good for one variable.

But I've got the problem because I want to implement multiple bus as the below

Source:

```
{test[13:10],thisistest[3:0],BUS[2:1]}
```

Result:

```
test[13]
test[12]
test[11]
test[10]
thisistest[3]
thisistest[2]
thisistest[1]
thisistest[0]
BUS[2]
BUS[1]
```

What I tried to do : 
I made similar function as

```
fun! split()
    let line = getline('.')
    let result = []
    let list = split(line, ",")
    let length = len(list)

    for i in length
        call ExpandIt(list[length])
    endfor
endf


fun! ExpandIt()
    let pat = '^\(.*\)\[\(\d\+\):\(\d\+\)\]\s*$'
    let line = getline('.')
    let lnr = line('.')
    if line !~ pat
        return
    endif
    let exestr = substitute(line,pat,'range(\2,\3,-1)','g')
    let text = substitute(line,pat,'\1','g')
    exec 'let range='.exestr
    let result = []
    for i in range
        call add(result, text.'['.i.']')
    endfor
    call append(lnr, result)
    exec lnr'.d'    
endf

nnoremap <F6> :call split()<cr>
```

Could you please let me know what am I supposed to do to go with right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the obvious errors in your added `split()` function (the function name must be capitalized to avoid `E128`, you pass an argument to `ExpandIt()`, but it doesn't take any, `length` is not iterable by `:for`), you seem to have a limited understanding of Vimscript, and just try to "make it work" through brute-force attempts. Therefore it was good to ask here on Stack Overflow, but please be aware that just relying on helpful strangers to fix things for you is a lopsided approach, so please use this and future questions to slowly but steadily learn about Vim, to become a master of it yourself!

The following seems to do what you're asking for, by doing the following modifications:

- fixing the obvious errors listed above
- collecting the `result` List in `Split()` is the right idea, but the actual insertion (`:call append()`) and deletion of the original line has to be moved there as well, and `ExpandIt()` has to return the result
- likewise, `ExpandIt()` needs to be passed the extracted element instead of directly getting the current line
- the `split()` of the line into comma-separated elements needs to drop the surrounding `{` and `}`; [`substitute()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) can do this.

```
fun! Split()
    let line = getline('.')
    let result = []

    for l in split(substitute(line, '[{}]', '', 'g'), ",")
        let result += ExpandIt(l)
    endfor

    let lnr = line('.')
    call append(lnr, result)
    exec lnr'.d'
endf

fun! ExpandIt(line)
    let pat = '^\(.*\)\[\(\d\+\):\(\d\+\)\]\s*$'
    if a:line !~ pat
        return
    endif
    let exestr = substitute(a:line,pat,'range(\2,\3,-1)','g')
    let text = substitute(a:line,pat,'\1','g')
    exec 'let range='.exestr
    let result = []
    for i in range
        call add(result, text.'['.i.']')
    endfor
    return result
endf

nnoremap <F6> :call Split()<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks perfectly working. BTW If I want it to increase such as test[10],test[11],test[12].. which one should I have to modify it? What I tried to do : change the range(\2, \3, +1) or for range in i... but all have errors.

Comment: If you want it to count up instead of down, `range(\2, \3, 1)` should do (also with the superfluous `+`). Of course, the `[X:Y]` then have to be `X < Y`, too.